# Finding the diagonal sum of 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, 2d

```
const diagonalSum = function (arr) {
    var length=arr.length -1;
     var sum=0;
     for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){//1<3
         sum+= arr[i][i]+arr[i][length-i]//[1][0]+
     }
       return sum;
   };
```

tried this , but 2nd and 3rd test cases are not getting passed. Any other logic?

```
const diagonalSum = function (arr) {
    var length=arr.length -1;
     var sum=0;
     for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){//1<3
         sum+= arr[i][i]+arr[i][length-i]//[1][0]+
     }
       return sum;
   };
```

searching any other logic

Comment: What's the difference between the two code snippets?

Comment: Probably the failing cases have an odd `length` in which case your code adds the central value twice. A quick fix: `sum+= arr[i][i]+ (length-i === i ? 0 : arr[i][length-i])`; a more thorough one would be to count for the even and odd cases separately.

Comment: What are the 2nd and 3rd test cases? Please add some sample data and the expected output

Answer (score -2):

This will work for you.

// An efficient Javascript  program to find
// sum of diagonals

```
function  printDiagonalSums(mat,n)
    {
        let principal = 0, secondary = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            principal += mat[i][i];
            
        }
     
        document.write("Principal Diagonal:"
                                + principal+"<br>");
                                     
        
    }
     
    // Driver code
     
        let a = [[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    [5, 6, 7, 8, 5 ],
                    [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
                    [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 5],
                [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 5]];
     
        printDiagonalSums(a, 5);
```